# JSON Time Format Using WCF Service

Tags: javascript, json, wcf

**WCF** Service is returning this **time** format 'PT10H49M18.363S'
What time format is this ?

Comment: [Pacific Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Time_Zone)?

Comment: Any standard method to format this json time ? ex: hh:mm